# UIToolbar above a Keyboard - iPhone SDK

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I have seen this question posted several times with no useful answers.  I am trying to place a toolbar above my UIKeyboard in my iPhone app, but am having difficulty. I found this [example](http://www.randomsequence.com/articles/adding-a-toolbar-with-next-previous-above-uitextfield-keyboard-iphone/) which works GREAT, except that my view is a `UITableView` instead of the standard `[self.view addsubview:...]`.  Can anyone figure out how to apply this to a `UITableView`? 
In short, I have several `UITextFields` in my table cells, so I want the toolbar to appear above the keyboard for those cells.

Many thanks,
Brett

Comment: Just answred my own question. For those that are interested, I used: [self.parentViewController.view addSubview:keyboardToolbar]

Comment: You should mark this as answered.  Either take Michael's or put in your own solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just don't use the table view directly as a view.
Use a view that will have a table view inside it.
This way you will be able to use the tutorial as is...

In my opinion this way is much better - I don't have view controller with a single table view in any of my applications. There is always something additional on the screen...

In addition, I don't think that using parentViewController is good solution.
Not always you have one.
Actually, I don't even understand how it works for you...

Answer (score 0):

A work around for this would be to create a hidden textfield in a viewcontroller and present it modally with it begin the first responder. The view can be completely transparent and the toolbar can be configured using the interface builder.